# qt: invalid property name "progress". (M16)

Tags: qt, qml

you can find my code example below. When I try to add "progress" qml says that**invalid property name "progress". (M16)** How can I fix this problem

```
ProgressBar {
     x:300
     y: 200
     value: 0.5
     background: Rectangle {
           radius: 10
           color: "red"
           border.color: "gray"
           border.width: 1
           implicitWidth: 200
           implicitHeight: 10
     }
     progress: Rectangle{

            }
          }
```

Comment: According [ProgressBar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-progressbar.html) documentation there is no **progress** property indeed. So the answer will depend on what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you'd like to customize the progress indicator with in the ProgressBar: use the **contentItem** property. See the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-progressbar) for more information.

Comment: Thank "contentItem" is what I was looking for :)

Comment: I did but my connection... "facePalm"